# Multiple visual studio and licenses

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, licensing, msdn

I need Visual Studio Professional 2010 and Visual Studio Professional 2015 on my system due to the requirements.  I am buying VS professional 2015 with MSDN.  Will it allow me to use both 2015 as well as pro 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you are licensed via MSDN, you can use each one.